# "No Limit" Versus "Unlimited"

Tags: word-choice

Senior programmer in my team in developing hotel management program and there is something about hotel rooms limit, how many room the hotel can provide to customer. He want to add option to indicate that hotel is sure to welcome any amount of customer and he was asking me that should we use "No Limit" or "Unlimited"

Comment: Surely the limiting factor is the number of rooms in the building?

Comment: Unless the hotel is being managed by David Hilbert

Comment: ...or Sarah Winchester

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the number of rooms the hotel can provide truly infinite? If so, you can use either one. But if it is not, then you must hit the limit at some point. Therefore "no limit to the rooms" or "unlimited rooms" would be — what's the word I'm looking for here? — a lie.

I suggest you qualify your statement by saying the number of rooms you can offer is "virtually unlimited," to make clear that this is just advertising-speak, and that if a billion people were to show up one night you would have to turn a few of them away.

Comment: I think that the context of the hotel system implies the context of "limited by availability" and that the terms "no limit" and "unlimited" apply only to *extra* limitations that might be applied to a customer.

Comment: @Unreason: The OP specifically speaks of "hotel room limit, how many room the hotel can provide to customer"; I don't see any indication that other factors are meant to be considered at all, much less in place of that principal condition.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is not [Hilbert's Hotel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Hotel), which not only had an infinite number of rooms, but could accommodate infinitely more guests even when already full by some deft room changes.

I suspect this is more of a questionnaire trying to deal with people who do not want to give a limit figure for the rooms.  So you might consider words like *any* or *not stated* or *unspecified*.